# After i fetch data and add it to redux my react app throws error a variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, axios

After i fetch data and add it to redux my react app throws error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'embed')** at line 371.
Here is line 371:

```html
<input name="color" type="color" className="color-pick" id="embed_color" ref={embedColor} defaultValue={config.guild.welcomeConfig.embed.embedColor} />
```

Here is the fetch:

```js
export const saveWelcomeConfig = (guildId, config ) => 
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url + `config/${guildId}/savewelcome`,
        data: {
            welcomeConfig: config
        },
        withCredentials: true
    })
```

And here is the action:

```js
export const saveWelcomeConfig = (config, guildId) => async (dispatch) => {
    try{
        const { data } = await api.saveWelcomeConfig( guildId, config )

        
        dispatch({
            type: 'SAVE_WELCOME_CONFIG',
            payload: data
        })
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

And the embed is in my redux's state. After i refresh page its working. But i dont want to refresh the page.

Comment: It's missing `welcomeConfig` in the data that's returned. Check the data payload and make sure it's being returned.

Comment: Thank you! Its working now. I sent a different data.

Comment: awesome glad it works for you!